# What's the code should behind this situation?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is the second time I'm asking here about it. I shall try to make it easier to give you the answer.

This is all about rewriteing rule. First of all, have a look below:

The following 4 php script is related to account managing of my php login script.

1. account.php
2. login.php
3. signup.php
4. logout.php

More details about the scripts:

1. Accout.php has 4-5 pages based on GET request. E.G. ?page=edit, ?page=view etc.
2. Login.php has only 2 pages, ?action=login and ?action=block.
3. Signup.php has 3 pages, ?page=process, ?page=process&step=1,2.
4. logout.php has only one page.

That's a part of my script. Now I'm interested to rewrite the ugly url. I want all the page has 'account' prefix.

1. account/edit
2. account/view
3. account/login
4. account/login/blocked
5. account/create
6. account/create/step/1
7. account/create/step/2
8. account/logout

I think I have cleared my question as much as I can. I have tried a lot but get failed. I hope you guys have the answer for me for "How could I do that?" or "What's the code should behind this situation?"

Please, I really need your help badly.

[Edit]

Thanks for your support @JonLin. Thanks a lot. But I need one more help from you. I hope if you help here i could do others.

Now i have,

1. forum.php?fid=1&p=2
2. thread.php?tid=1&p=2

(its not only 1 or 2, its [(0-9)+] )

How to do it like this

1. forum/f1/anything/page-2
2. forum/t1/anything/page-2

I've tried your signup.php code with a little edit, but its not working.

All of my pages of the script is formatted like this, any.php?xid=n&p=n ( n != 1 or n > 1 ).

So i want the same prefix used for any.php, that related to the any.php, for i.e. any.php has a book.php i want the url like this, any/a1/anything/page-2 and any/b1/anything/page-2 ( page-n will be shown when n > 1 )

Please help me here, I am stuck here. Thank you very much for your friendly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# to account.php
RewriteRule ^account/edit/?$ /account.php?page=edit [L]
RewriteRule ^account/view/?$ /account.php?page=view [L]
#etc... 

# to login.php
RewriteRule ^account/login/?$ /login.php?action=login [L]
RewriteRule ^account/login/blocked/?$ /login.php?action=block [L]

# to signup.php
RewriteRule ^account/create/? /signup.php?page=process [L]
RewriteRule ^account/create/step/([12])/?$ /signup.php?page=process&step=$1 [L]

# to logout.php
RewriteRule ^account/logout/?$ /logout.php [L]
```

Comment: Signup.php has 3 pages, ?
page=process, ?
page=process&step=1,2.


# to signup.php
RewriteRule ^account/
create/? /signup.php?
page=process [L]
RewriteRule ^account/
create/step/([12])/?
$ /signup.php?
page=process&step=$1
[L]


-Not working for this..

Comment: @FarhanIhsas `step/([12])` matches `step/1` or `step/2`.

Comment: What about if I want to use it on another script. Suppose, N=n=numerical and Z=z=alphabetical→→→
category.php?id=N&page=n →→ browse/cN/Z/n

→→→
sub-category.php?id=N&page=n →→ browse/scN/Z/n
→→→
i mean, sub-/category.php?id=1&page=2 would be browse/(c/sc)1/anything/2 (I don't want 1, its > 1, 1 would be assumed )

Please help me, i don't have only the signup.php, i need it too. If you can help here, I can do others, Because I have learned it from you.

Comment: @FarhanIhsas you should open a new question because you can't format in a comment and it's too hard to read

Comment: Please read the question again, I have updated it..Thanks in advance.