# What to do here for mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This question haven't been answered completely and a part of this question: [What's the code should behind this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285403/whats-the-code-should-behind-this-situation/)

The un-answered part is here with a little edit, please I need your help. Thanks in advance for your help.

I have:

1. forum.php?fid=1&p=2
2. thread.php?tid=1&p=2

( the numerous values are not only 1 or 2, its ([0-9]+) )

How to do it like this:

1. forum/f1/anything/page-2
2. forum/t1/anything/page-2

For more:

All of my pages of the script is formatted like this: any.php?xid=n&p=n ( n != 1 or n > 1 ).

So i want the same prefix used for
any.php, that related to the any.php, for i.e. any.php has a link to book.php, so I want the url like this:

1. any/a1/anything/page-2
2. any/b1/anything/page-2

( One more thing, page-n will be shown when n > 1, so it needs to be worked if it is: any/a1/anything. Please help me, I am stuck here. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum/f(\d+)/[^/]+(?:/page-(\d+))?/?$ /forum.php?fid=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/t(\d+)/[^/]+(?:/page-(\d+))?/?$ /thread.php?tid=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

Please, note that `any/a1/anything` is being redirected as `any.php?aid=1&p=` i.e. `p` would come but without a value. For all practical purposes (and since the redirected URL is never made visible to the client) it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @anubhava, TQ :) Hey, you were helping this guy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19314835/1237040), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19316478/1237040) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19318162/1237040). Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309831/1237040). Had to delete my answer as OP kept second guessing it and was convinced its wrong. See, if any of the info there and the comments below can help you improve any of your answers. Just sharing.

Comment: Aha it is the same guy :P I didn't realize that. My gut feeling is that mod_rewrite isn't even enabled for him. Left a comment for him to respond.

Comment: Thanks, I was really in a problem. But finally I've realised it was my script problem. Thanks to SO and @Ravi. It helps me. Thanks.